# False proof using Nullstellensatz : Let $J = (S)$ an ideal of polynomials then $\sqrt{S} = \sqrt{J}.$ What's wrong?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, ideals, solution-verification

Let $K$ be an algebraically closed field, $S \subset R = K[X_1,X_2,...,X_n]$ and  $J = (S)$
the ideal generated by $S$. Let $V$ and $I$ denote the usual correspondences between $R$ and $K^n$

The Nullstellensatz states (among other things) that for any $J \subset R$:

$$ I(V(J)) = \sqrt{J}$$

Since $V(S) = V(J),$ we have $\sqrt{J} = \sqrt{S}.$

This proof can't be correct. Take $S = \{1\}$ then $J = R$ but

$$ \sqrt R = R $$ and

$$ \sqrt{\{ 1\}} = \{g \vert \exists n : g^n = 1 \} \neq R.$$

Where did I go wrong ?

Comment: The problem is the definition of the radical of $1$. You are mistakenly taking the radical of the singleton $\{1\}$, when you need to be taking the radical of the ideal generated by 1. So it should read $\{g \vert \exists n : g^n \in (1) = R \}$. Notice I took out your equal sign and replaced it with \in symbol. And of course this is the whole ring by taking $n = 1$ for all elements $g$.

Comment: @NicholasRoberts Do you mean that $$ \sqrt{J} := \{ g \vert \exists n : g^n \in (J) \}$$ and not $$\sqrt{J}  = \{ g \vert \exists n : g^n \in J \}$$ ?

Comment: It's the second one you wrote. You can only take radicals of ideals. The singleton set $\{1\}$ is not an ideal.

Comment: @NicholasRoberts this looks like an answer to the question to me. Would you care to record this below?

Comment: I have posted as an answer @KReiser Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per request, I will write my comment as an answer. The problem here is that you have (mistakenly) taken the radical of the singleton set $\{1\}$. The singleton set $\{1\}$ is not an ideal. We would rather take radicals of ideals because then it can be shown quite easily that the radical of an ideal is also an ideal. Thus, we should take the radical of the **ideal generated by $\textbf{1}$** which is denoted as $\sqrt{(1)}$.

So the correct formulation of your last line would be: $$\sqrt{(1)} = \{g \vert \exists n : g^n \in (1) = R \} = R.$$